# Bodyparser behavior after second question mark

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I wrote a simple API which will return request.query as a response.

[image]

The behavior is little different than what I am expecting.

1. redirectto -- I am getting the only name as part of response redirectto param.
2. id -- I am getting an array in response.

Why is this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters that contain reserved characters should be URL encoded or they will fail to parse correctly.

The properly encoded URL should look something like this:

http://localhost:8082/redirect?requesttype=click&id=79992&redirectto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fredirect%3Fname%3Djohn%26id%3D123

Comment: can i use any method in bodyparser to encode the Url before bodyparser.json()?

Comment: The URL needs to be encoded before the request is made, like the link I provided. You can't encode the URL on the server with express, the URL needs to be encoded before it reaches express so that express can properly parse it. You can use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the redirect URL when you are building this link, assuming this link is being generated programmatically.